# Windows 7 local network video streaming skips

Tags: windows-7, networking, video-streaming

I have a pretty simple setup - file server with movies, HTPC in living room, various desktops and laptops. All the hardware is fairly recent and entirely capable of decoding 1080p h264. But for some reason, I get skipping if I try to stream 1080p movies over the network, and even with 720p movies, trying to jump to different parts of the movie takes several seconds to happen, followed by around 10 seconds of slow/fast sets of frames, distorted colors/blocking, etc., before things start displaying correctly and syncing with the audio.

I've tried: different video players (media player classic, WMP, VLC) and different codec packs (CCCP, Shark007). Out of ideas. (VLC works measurably better than the other two, but the issue still shows up.)

Specs: 
Gigabit network, i7 desktop, dual-core HTPC and fileserver.

Comment: Disabling Remote Differential Compression fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

HD video takes a LOT of network bandwidth, how do you have your pc connected to the storage, is it through ethernet cable, if so does it go straight to the storage or does it go through a switch, if it is wireless, can we have some details on the wireless points / routers ?. The best way to debug this problem if it is connected via ethernet cable is to get a 1 metre cable and hook it straight up to your pc and put your storage device next to your pc, if it stops skipping you know its either a too long cable / faulty cable / faulty network switch / router, if it connected via wireless try hooking it up via ethernet cable.

Comment: Its not a bandwidth problem. I can copy any movie from the file server to any other machine at near full link speed - which is the issue in a nutshell, really: if it takes me less than sixty seconds to copy an entire 4 gig movie, why are there any problems playing/jumping through the movie? [Details - network is wired, gigabit switch, N900 Netgear router (the issue existed with two prior routers, so its unlikely to be that).]